# When click on div > add class. Whats problam in my JS?

Tags: javascript

When I click on a block a class should be added to it.

I seem to have done everything right, but the code does not work.

But it shows me an error in the javascript. I cannot understand what I did wrong.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

Please, help to solve the error.

```js
function myFunction() {
 var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 element.classList.add("50squareclick");
}
```

```css
._50_square {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 0px;
  perspective: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg) perspective(2000px);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg) perspective(2000px);
}

.blockbasic_card_rotate {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image_rotate {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.video_rotate {
 display:none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #282828;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.image_rot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/*animation*/

.50squareclick{
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(40deg) perspective(2000px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blockbasic_card_rotate">
 <div onclick="myFunction()" class="_50_square" id="myDIV">
  <div class="image_rotate"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/607d73367d4164322c697517/607d73367d416404e469754e_placeholder%203.svg" loading="lazy" alt="" class="image_rot"></div>
  <div class="video_rotate">
   <div class="w-embed-youtubevideo">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vb0ZWc70gOk?rel=0&amp;controls=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;mute=0&amp;start=20" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;pointer-events:auto" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Pete — Shouldn't mater. It doesn't get called until the click happens.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't demonstrate the problem. (Likely the issue has to do with how you are trying to load the JS into your HTML document)

Comment: Note that a class name cannot start with a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a few changes to the code you provided, i have passed `this` as the paramater and got rid of

`var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");` coz you its irrevelant and it should be fine now
one thing to take note of is the naming of the classes

> HTML5 supports numbers as id and class name , but css selector have
> some rules , A valid name should start with a letter (a-z)[A-Z] , an
> underscore (_), or a hyphen (-) which is followed by any numbers,
> hyphens, underscores, letters.

[read more on that here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiQxKmQp57wAhVATBUIHQkMBWAQFjABegQIAxAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Ffront-end-weekly%2Fcss-selector-for-element-which-have-numbers-as-class-name-b6a089989199&usg=AOvVaw2jSMcLOqQESeUJxEUIR2zT)

```js
function myFunction(e) {
 //var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
 e.classList.add("_50squareclick");
 console.log(e)

}
```

```css
._50_square {
  position: relative;
  width: 50vh;
  height: 50vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-perspective: 0px;
  perspective: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg) perspective(2000px);
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(0deg) perspective(2000px);
}

.blockbasic_card_rotate {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image_rotate {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.video_rotate {
 display:none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #282828;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.image_rot {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/*animation*/

.50squareclick{
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotateY(40deg) perspective(2000px);
}
```

```html
<div class="blockbasic_card_rotate">
 <div onclick="myFunction(this)" class="_50_square" id="myDIV">
  <div class="image_rotate"><img src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/607d73367d4164322c697517/607d73367d416404e469754e_placeholder%203.svg" loading="lazy" alt="" class="image_rot"></div>
  <div class="video_rotate">
   <div class="w-embed-youtubevideo">
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vb0ZWc70gOk?rel=0&amp;controls=1&amp;autoplay=0&amp;mute=0&amp;start=20" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;pointer-events:auto" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thaks for your solve. I'm realy didnt anderstand why my code didnt work.

Comment: does it still work without changing this `.50squareclick{` to this `._50squareclick{` ?